# accessing control item when given inner template element

Tags: c#, wpf, treeviewitem

I have a `TreeviewItem` with a `style` set to this

```
    <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox x:Name="checkbox_treeview" Checked="treeView_AfterCheck" Unchecked="treeView_AfterCheck"/>
                            <Image x:Name="image_treeview" Width="16"/>
                            <local:WPFEditableTextBlock x:Name="label_TreeView" Text="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I am able to access the `checkbox` of the template by doing this

```
TreeViewItem folderNode = new TreeViewItem();
Style style = this.FindResource("TreeViewItemStyle") as Style;
folderNode.Style = style;
ControlTemplate controlTemplate = folderNode.Template;
var templatedControl = folderNode.Template.LoadContent() as FrameworkElement;
CheckBox chbx = (CheckBox)templatedControl.FindName("checkbox_treeview");
```

once I am able to access this `checkbox` I have it go to the `checked` event handler.  within that I want to be able to access the `treeViewItem` that contains that `checkbox`, but I can't figure out how to do this. Please help me out!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the `treeViewItem` from the `checkbox` defined in the template you could pass it in the `Tag` property from xaml like so:

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox x:Name="checkbox_treeview" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}" Checked="treeView_AfterCheck" Unchecked="treeView_AfterCheck"/>
                        <Image x:Name="image_treeview" Width="16"/>
                        <local:WPFEditableTextBlock x:Name="label_TreeView" Text="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
 </ControlTemplate>
```

and here how to retrieve it from the event handler:

```
private void treeView_AfterCheck(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var tvi = ((sender as CheckBox).Tag as TreeViewItem);
}
```

Comment: when I add this into my code it says that the checkboxes .tag property is null and my var tvi is also null.

Comment: Make sure that you are using the `RelativeSource` binding correctly!

Comment: How do I make sure I'm using it correctly? I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I've looked into it and it is saying that my checkbox's template parent is null so that's why the RelativeSource is not working correctly.  any Ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: The code you provided above doesn't allow you to access the `TreeViewItem`, you are simply creating a new TreeViewItem with no visibility on the ui, and load it with the defined style.

Comment: make sure to add a TreeViewItem in your xaml, or from the codebehind then you can use the `treeView_AfterCheck`. You could create a simple demo project with a treeview populated with some items and you will see that using the Tag to pass the parent does work :-)

Comment: I was able to figure out my problem. thanks you!!  It turns out that my code was going to the check changed event before I added the new TreeViewItem to my TreeView.  once I fixed that, your code allowed me to access the TreeViewItem I wanted,